# How do I make VS2010 prefer one include directory over another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to use the `XInput.h` file from the DirectX SDK, but this file also exists in the Windows SDK (and it's a different variation of the file).

I've tried adding `$(DXSDK_DIR)Include;` to the Include Directories in the project settings, before and also after `$(IncludePath)` just to try and make it work.

I got VS to compile my program using the DirectX SDK version somehow, but after cleaning it went back to using the Windows SDK version... it just seems almost random, is it?

Comment: Did you originally use VS-2010 for the project or you have migrated your project from previous VS to VS-2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem trying to use the August 2007 DirectX SDK (for DirectDraw) with Visual Studio 2010.

What I ended up doing was removing all of the default include paths, and only specifying the DirectX SDK path in the include list, then checking "Inherent from parent or project defaults", which includes the framework SDK.

Worked for me, hope this helps.

Comment: I think this works, but I also managed to get it working by adding the DX include before the other includes -- but this only works once I cleaned everything. Very tricky.

Comment: @nbolton It's very erratic to say the least, I hesitated to even submit this as an answer because it's just so... "eh". Glad you got it working though.