# How do I make CMake prefer one include directory over another?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

A follow up from...

- [How do I make VS2010 prefer one include directory over another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976759/how-do-i-make-vs2010-prefer-one-include-directory-over-another)

... how do I make CMake generate a VS2010 project which prefers one include directory over another? In my case, I need it to prefer the DirectX input dir over the Windows SDK dir.

Comment: Can you list that path first?

Comment: It's actually an environment variable: `$(DXSDK_DIR)`

Comment: This looks promising: http://ogre-paged.googlecode.com/hg/examples/CMakeLists.txt?r=adf09c27beee3fbcb94d190c2e09ddc34926218b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like this is the way to do it, though not ideal:

First, create a DXSDK_DIR environment variable with the DX SDK path, e.g.: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)`

Then, add the following lines to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
include_directories($ENV{DXSDK_DIR}/Include)
link_directories("$ENV{DXSDK_DIR}/Lib/x86")
```

Like I said, not ideal as it doesn't use the VS macro, but I guess that's CMake for you. I welcome anyone to suggest a better way.